# spring cloud Gateway ip forwarding

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

Here's my code for forwarding requests to my website:

```
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routToMyWebsite(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
            .route("my-id", p -> p
                .path("/**")
                .uri("http://my-website.com"))
            .build();
    }
```

When I look at nginx logs in my-website.com, IP address is the IP of the machine where my gateway application runs. How to forward the original IP address?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the [XForwarded Headers Filter](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#xforwarded-headers-filter) is activated by default.
So if you display the `X-Forwarded-For` header in the Nginx logs, you should see the original IP of the client.